# Change date output format

Tags: java, database, h2

I'm using H2 db in my java application and i need to get the date from it. Everything is ok, but wneh i have 1-digit number of day or month, it gives me this format 2014-4-8. Is it possile to get something like this (2014-04-08), with zeros without parsing it and formatting via the application?

Comment: Dates don't have "a format". Whatever format you are seeing is applied by whatever application you use to view the data.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If you use H2, and store the data as a "date", then the default `toString` representation is already `2014-04-08`. It looks like some component or your application explicitly use the shorter format. You'll need to provide details and possibly some source code on what you do exactly.

Answer (score 1):

If you use struts2 in your front end.below tag might be helpful to you

```
<s:date name="somedate" format="EEE, MMM dd, yyyy " />
```